# Javascript events (click)

Tags: javascript, events, dom, element

My website works basically with javascript. the server returns the html in a JSON array then javascript will add it to DOM.
My problem is with events.
Should I add the click event to body/window and then check if target match or add event to every element ? (the most events will be in the feed, where elements have same class):

```
    <div id="feed_1">
           <div class="like_button" data-click="something here">Like</div>
    </div>
<div id="feed_2">
           <div class="like_button" data-click="something here">Like</div>
    </div>
```

note: I'm not using jQuery

Comment: Are those "i" attributes meant to be IDs?

Comment: sorry: yes the "i" mean Id. => updated

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking whether or not you should add an even to every element in the HTML document, or to have one event listener that specifies a target upon a click, the better way is definitely the latter.

With events that work with a large number of elements, we enforce DRY principles through the use of event delegation. This involves declaring an event listener with the event parameter, and then triggering the event onto the event target. example:

```
var el = document.getElementByID('container');
el.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    doSomething(e.target); // do something to the target element
});
```

The idea here is that your container element encompasses everything you wish to be 'clickable', however, when you click an element within the container, the event will only fire for that clicked element. This way we prevent having to define an event listener for each individual element.

Hope this helps.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/628yvp8f/    I've made this right now. that's a simple version. is that ok ?